# Is it possible to get the real username inside of a script that was called using sudo?

Tags: bash

I have a script that I call with sudo -- `sudo script`, and I want to be able to see the username of the user running the script (not root).

Sticking `whoami` or `id -un` inside the script just gives me `root`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

sudo creates an environment variable called SUDO_USER. You can use it in your script like so:

`echo $SUDO_USER`

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the SUDO_USER, SUDO_UID or SUDO_GID environmental variables to find this information.